# sql if null show 0

Tags: mysql

In SQL how do you show 0 if record is null?

```
select sales_id, totalbuy, totalsell, totalbuy + totalsell as total from
(select sales_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
from car_orders 
where sales_id in ('sales1', 'sales2', 'sales3', 'sales4')only
GROUP BY sales_id)q
order by total desc
limit 0, 10;
```

After `car_orders` I have tried inserting*(car_orders+ISNULL(car_orders,0)) but get an error.

Comment: `car_orders` is tableName right?

Comment: yes it is the table name

Comment: also, you can't `select` `from` an expression, only from a table or another `select`

Comment: the above tag works but I want to show 0 when record is null

Comment: @userH you can use `ifnull` on any column, but not the whole table

Comment: A record can't be null, only a column can be.

Comment: @Barmar a set of columns from a table may be null because it's a right operand to a left join (or vice versa)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, but we still don't allow operating on the row as a whole. If you want to know if the outer join resulted in a null, you have to check one of the columns (it's best to use the join column, since it can't have an actual null in the table).

Comment: @Barmar I know, I'm just trying to explain OP's thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building from Sohnee's answer, here is the SQL I think you want to use:

```
SELECT 
    sales_id,
    IFNULL(totalbuy, 0),
    IFNULL(totalsell, 0),
    IFNULL(totalbuy, 0) + IFNULL(totalsell, 0) as total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        sid as sales_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN side = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN side = 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
    FROM 
        ( SELECT 'sales1' as sid UNION SELECT 'sales2' UNION SELECT 'sales3' UNION SELECT 'sales4' ) mysalesids
    LEFT OUTER JOIN car_orders
      ON sales_id = sid
    GROUP BY
       sales_id
) q
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

The key to the above is the "LEFT OUTER JOIN".  If you can have the 'sales1', 'sales2', 'sales3' values in their own table, that would be preferable rather than having a sub-select.

Hope this helps,

john...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `+`, both arguments must be of the same type. I can't tell from your question what `car` is, but I assume it isn't compatible with a `0`.

It is better to use `CONCAT` in these cases.

```
CONCAT(car, IFNULL(car_orders, 0))
```

If `car_orders` is a table, it isn't valid here - you must use a column, i.e. `car_orders.MyColumn`

**How To Use IFNULL**

I don't think you can end up with a null here, given your query, buy you would use IFNULL like this:

```
SELECT 
    sales_id,
    IFNULL(totalbuy, 0),
    IFNULL(totalsell, 0),
    IFNULL(totalbuy, 0) + IFNULL(totalsell, 0) as total
FROM
(
    SELECT
        sales_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN side = 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN side = 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
    FROM
        car_orders 
    WHERE
        sales_id in ('sales1', 'sales2', 'sales3', 'sales4')
    GROUP BY
       sales_id
) q
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: The MySQL function is called [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: car_orders is the name of the table

Comment: @tadman quite correct - always catches me out when I'm switching between TSQL and MySql!

Comment: `car_orders` is table name so `IFNULL` and `COALESCE` won't work!

Comment: @userH what did you try? If you are still jamming the table name in it won't work - see the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: select sales_id, totalbuy, totalsell, totalbuy + totalsell as total from
(select sales_id, SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'buy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalbuy, 
SUM(CASE WHEN side= 'sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalsell 
from car_orders**(car_orders+ISNULL(car_orders,0)) 
where sales_id in ('sales1', 'sales2', 'sales3', 'sales4')only
GROUP BY sales_id)q
order by total desc
limit 0, 10;

Comment: @userH as I mentioned in my answer, you can't do this on the table, only on the columns. I will add an example to help.

Comment: @userH then it won't work, as already stated three times at least

Comment: @userH may i ask why table is null?

Comment: Sorry John I should've been more clear. If sales and buys for a certain sales_id is null I want it to show 0. It is possible a sales_id has not sold or bought anything hence null

Comment: Sohnee when using an alias, how would you insert the query to get 0=null?

Comment: Try replacing the "FROM car_orders WHERE..." clause with this:  FROM (
SELECT 'sales1' as sid
UNION SELECT 'sales2' 
UNION SELECT 'sales3' 
UNION SELECT 'sales4' 
) mysalesids
LEFT OUTER JOIN car_orders  ON sales_id = sid

Comment: Sohnees is close, just use my FROM WHERE.  Or do you want me to post my own answer?

Comment: Hey John I am a complete novice so would appreciate if you could post your answer. Thanks Buddy!